# Flutter pub get Gives error message whenever .yaml file is changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The orignal pubspec.yaml files works fine when generated through "flutter create {project_name}" but suppose I want to try to add a dependency such as fluttertoast it gives error message

```
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0-170.0.dev <3.0.0'
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
    fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
        flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
        flutter:

          uses-material-design: true
```

This gives the error:

```
Error on line 10, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A version constraint must be a string.
   ╷
10 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
11 │ │ 
12 │ │     cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
13 │ │     fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
14 │ │ 
15 │ │     dev_dependencies:
16 │ │       flutter_test:
17 │ │         sdk: flutter
18 │ │         flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
19 │ │         flutter:
20 │ │ 
21 │ └           uses-material-design: true
   ╵
Running "flutter pub get" in textfield...                               
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

And know even if I delete the fluttertoast dependency

It still results in the error

```
Error on line 10, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A version constraint must be a string.
   ╷
10 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
11 │ │ 
12 │ │     cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
13 │ │       #    fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
14 │ │ 
15 │ │     dev_dependencies:
16 │ │       flutter_test:
17 │ │         sdk: flutter
18 │ │         flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
19 │ │         flutter:
20 │ │ 
21 │ └           uses-material-design: true
   ╵
Running "flutter pub get" in textfield...                               
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

flutter --version output -->

```
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1112 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8294d9e91e (24 hours ago) • 2022-06-05 13:38:04 -0400
Engine • revision 9e4f372577
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-170.0.dev) • DevTools 2.14.0
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed `dependencies:` before `sdk:`.

Set it like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.15.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
```

Refer this [example](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#example) for more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yaml is indent sensitive. Easiest way to add a package is to run `flutter pub add fluttertoast' in terminal. To fix the error that you are facing make the indentation of flutter toast same as flutter in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: any
  flutter toast : ^8.0.9
```

Comment: flutter pub add fluttertoast worked like a charm, I didn't realise that it's indent sensitive. Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked ! Since you are a new contributor, if you feel the answers are right please accept the answers and if you find any question or answer to be helpful please upvote too. It will help in growing the community.